# How to Loads environment variables from .env to getenv() PHP MVC

Tags: php

I want to set up an environment variable and initialize App but when I echo the app_name it doese not show anything.

**Code in .env file is like below**

```
APP_URL=http://ecom.me
APP_ENV=local
APP_NAME="ACME E-commerce Store"

#database

DB_DRIVER='mysql'
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=store
DB_USERNAME=store
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Code in _env.php is like below**

```
<?php

define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../'));
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(BASE_PATH);
$dotenv->load();
   
?>
```

**Code in index.php is like below**

```
<?php 
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/config/_env.php';
$name = getenv('APP_NAME');
echo $name;
?>
```

any help will be highly appricated

Comment: If you are using Symfony's DotEnv component, you can call the [`usePutenv()`](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv/blob/204a9dc6f70a13d9d24ebbf2c5ce51be235f3d7b/Dotenv.php#L74) method

Comment: it is    composer require vlucas/phpdotenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#putenv-and-getenv), you should use `Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable()`

So instead of:

```php
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(BASE_PATH);
```

Use:

```php
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(BASE_PATH);
```